# VBA Does Not Return Correct System Date

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a procedure that will send a report out if the report has not been sent out on that date. When it sends the report it will run a query that inserts the date and report name into a table.

The problem is the date that it is returning is February 19th, 2019. I would understand if it was a formatting issue but this date is completely off.

```
Dim strFile As String
Dim strTo As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strBody As String
Dim InReport As String
Dim InDate As Date

strFile = Forms!frmMain!strFile
strTo = "email"
strSubject = "subject"
strBody = "body"
InReport = "ReportName"
InDate = Date

    If DCount("*", "tblEmailTracking", "[SentDate]=#" & InDate & "#") > 0 Then

    Exit Sub
        'do nothing
Else
        'send email
        
    DoCmd.OpenReport "ReportName", acViewPreview, , , acHidden
       Reports("ReportName").Caption = strFile
       
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "ReportName", acFormatPDF, strTo, strCC, , 
    strSubject, strBody, False
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblEmailTracking(SentDate, SentReport) VALUES('" & InDate & "', '" & InReport & "');"
    
    DoCmd.Close acReport, "ReportName"

End If
```

Comment: if you put a breakpoint on your first IF statement and check the locals window, what is the value of InDate?  Also, what's the 'it' you're referring to when you say "problem is the date that it is returning is February 19th, 2019"?  Do you mean the variable in VBA, or the report you're getting back, or something else?

Comment: Have you verified what `Debug.Print InDate` outputs just after you have set the value?  Also, isn't it `InDate = Date()` as opposed to `InDate = Date`?

Comment: Date() automagically resolves itself to Date (at least on my machine).

Comment: I feel it's a better-safe-than-sorry situation with `Date()`, which also helps differentiate when you look at the code (hence `As Date` and `Date` are both orange in the snippit); was a quick thing that stuck out to me, beyond verifying the actual term in the immediate window.  Unrelated, *automagically* is a term to carry forward...

Comment: Fair enough.  In my VBA window, you can't put in Date(). Well you can, but as soon as you hit 'Enter' the system removes the ().  I'm wondering if the user is using Visual Studio (and maybe vb.NET?) or some other editor as the standard VBA editor doesn't look like that...unless I've been missing out on formatting features of the VBA editor.

Comment: What is the type of the column SentDate of the table tblEmailTracking? What locale are you using? Have you checked your system date?

Comment: Except for the line wrapping of the DoCmd.SendObject line, looks like VBA. Lack of line continuation character should trigger compile error.

Comment: Should that date have been mm/dd/yyyy of 2/19/2021? Where is code that inserts data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the work to SQL:

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblEmailTracking(SentDate, SentReport) VALUES( Date(), '" & InReport & "');"
```